# docker-compose health check portmapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have the following docker-compose :

```
services:
  my-fine-service:
    restart: always
    image: 'my-fine-image:${ARTEFACT_VERSION}'
    ports:
       - 8380:8080
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/actuator/health"]
    interval: 30s
    timeout: 3s
    retries: 10
```

I am not quite sure if I must use Port 8080 or Port 8380 for the HealthCheck URL or if even using my-fine-service as the hostname for curl

Comment: Well, when you tested out both options, what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HEALTHCHECK**

The HEALTHCHECK instruction has two forms:

> `HEALTHCHECK [OPTIONS] CMD command` **(check container health by
>   running a command inside the container)**
>
> `HEALTHCHECK NONE` (disable
>   any healthcheck inherited from the base image)

As it will run a command inside container then it should be `8080`

[health-check](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Comment: It is port 8080 as it runs inside the container as you said. The real problem I faced was that curl is not available in my image. I have to make a new one with curl available